# Firebase filling array twice -- Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, firebase

I have two String arrays: one that holds order numbers, and one that holds addresses.

I pull data from Firebase in viewDidAppear using a function that contains the following:

```
    self.localOrderNumberArray.removeAll()
    self.localAddressArray.removeAll()

    self.orderNumbers.removeAll()
    self.addresses.removeAll()

    self.tableView.reloadData()

    if onItsWayCompanyNameStoreNumberCourierNumberRootRef != nil {

        let deliveryRef = onItsWayCompanyNameStoreNumberCourierNumberRootRef.childByAppendingPath("deliveries")

        deliveryRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

            self.orderNumbers.removeAll()
            self.addresses.removeAll()

            print(snapshot.value.objectForKey("orderNumber"))
            let orderNumberPulledFromFirebase = snapshot.value.objectForKey("orderNumber") as! String
            self.localOrderNumberArray.insert(orderNumberPulledFromFirebase, atIndex: 0)

            let addressPulledFromFirebase = snapshot.value.objectForKey("address") as! String
            self.localAddressArray.insert(addressPulledFromFirebase, atIndex: 0)

            self.orderNumbers = self.localOrderNumberArray
            self.addresses = self.localAddressArray

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        })
    }
```

The function fills a UITableView with the data pulled from Firebase.

Everything works great when I first run the app. I can add data to Firebase through a different function, and the function above will pull the new data into the UITableView just fine.

However, when I segue to a different view controller (another UITableView, in this case), and then come back to the view that holds the function above, the function fills the order number and address arrays twice **when I add new data**.

If I segue to the other UITableView a second time, and then come back to view that holds the function above, the function fills the order number and address arrays three times **when I add new data**. And so on and so on.

It's the strangest thing. I can't figure it out, and it's about to drive me over the edge. Please help.

Comment: @JohnV Sounds good. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `deliveryRef.observeEventType` in `viewDidAppear`. `viewDidAppear` will be called each time the ViewController is presented. So when you segue to other ViewController and comes back, `viewDidAppear` will be called again and `deliveryRef.observeEventType` is registered again. So effectively there are two listeners doing the same job in your viewController which will add duplicate data to the array.

You have to implement a logic to do `observeEventType` only once in the ViewController.

Comment: Thanks! You got me going in the right direction.

For those who may have this problem in the future: I set the "deliveryRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in" to a handle (similar to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27124118/firebase-removing-observers)). Then, as part of the segue function, I called deliveryRef.removeObserverWithHandle(handle!). That disconnected the observer, which then allowed the observer to register for the first time when I returned to the original view.